# Ember-Model init issue

Tags: ember.js, ember-model

I concatinate my application code from multiple js files into one js file. Therefore I can't control the order, and to be honest would not want to. To specify a custom adapter with ember-model you need to create an instance of it like so:

```
App.User.adapter = Ember.CustomAdapter.create();
```

So if the CustomAdapter's code appears after the above statement I get the *[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined]* error.

```
App.User.adapter = App.CustomAdapter.create();

App.CustomAdapter = Ember.Adapter.extend({
    // custom
});
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: you should use the correct order, there is now reliable way around this, IMO the tool you are using to concatenate should support ordering the imports...

Comment: Meh, maintaining order just doesn't seem right...

Comment: it's javascript right? javascript cares about order...

Answer (score 0):

The order of code loading is very, very important.  That's just a fact of life.  You need to either figure out how to make your current tool load things in the order that you want, or you need a new tool.